# Can not stop the loop of importing rows from a sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in the loop. I want to import lines that contain "X" in their first cell but :

- It doesn't paste them from the first row
- It pastes them too many times

Can someone help me ?

```
 Sub refresh()
    '
    ' refresh Macro
    '
    ' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
    '
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long

    Set wksSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set wksDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque S")
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").ClearContents 'Works directly, without selection

    lngRow = wksDest.Cells(wksDest.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To wksSrc.Range("A" & wksSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      If wksSrc.Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
        wksSrc.Range(wksSrc.Cells(i, 2), wksSrc.Cells(i, 20)).Copy

        wksDest.Range("B" & lngRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't paste from first row? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want it to paste from the row number 6 but it does from the buttom of the sheet and it paste it many times ( 6 or 7 times).

Comment: You mean starting at row 6?

Comment: Yes, exactly from B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub refresh()    
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long

Set wksSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
Set wksDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque S")

wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").Delete
wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").ClearContents 'Works directly, without selection

lngRow = 6
LastRow = wksSrc.Range("A" & wksSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

  If wksSrc.Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
    wksSrc.Range(wksSrc.Cells(i, 2), wksSrc.Cells(i, 20)).Copy
    wksDest.Range("B" & lngRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
  End If
Next i
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This version is optimized (not using a For loop)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub refreshAnalyse()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque S")

    ws2.Range("B6:AP" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        ws1.Range("B2:AP" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
        ws2.Activate: ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```